# Google Play service issue with MC40 device

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have installed built and installed an android app on MC40 device. The app uses internally GCM services. MC40 does not have google play services pre-installed.So I have included google play services in gradle `compile com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0` and bundled with app but when I run app on MC40 device ,it still asks for google play services has to be installed. is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: if the device does not come with google play services installed no there is no solution.

Comment: Compiling play-services into your app just gives you the interface to Google Play Services - it does not install the services themselves. Without the Google Play apps and libraries installed, your app will not work.